# Calculate tangent for measurement data

Tags: matlab, plot, numeric

I have some measurement data which I want to plot. I plot only the points and used the `Curve Fitting` Toolbox to generate a regression function which I plot.

Now I want to calculate and plot the tangent on a certain point. How can I do that using `Matlab`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have point and function, you can calculate the tangent which is:

let say the desired index is 5. y = mx+n

```
m = (diff(y) ./ diff(y)) (5)
n = y(5)-x(5)*m
```

and then

```
hold on
```

`plot (x, (m*x+n));`

**links:**

http://www.kxcad.net/cae_MATLAB/toolbox/curvefit/bqxox7w.html
http://www.weizmann.ac.il/matlab/toolbox/curvefit/cfit.html
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/170100

Comment: yeah that works if I have the points. Let's say I have 10 data points. I've done an interpolation using `Curve Fitting` Toolbox and got a `cfit` object. How do I get the interpolated values beneath the data points?

Comment: @Razer added links tell me if it helped you if not I'll write you the code

Comment: I just found myself the function feval(). I'll try with that.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @0x90 I got the solution:

```
zerocross = ceil(fzero(fit, 1000));
x_tan = zerocross-101:0.1:zerocross+100;
y_tan = feval(fit, x_tan);

k = (diff(y_tan) ./ diff(x_tan));
k = k(length(k) / 2); % get zero point
d = y_tan(5)-x_tan(5)*k;

plot (x_tan, (k*x_tan+d));
```